# Does anyone know how to make Arc GIS Maps render faster?

Tags: arcgis

I noticed Arc Gis maps render really slow.  When you zoom, it renders slow.  When you pan, it renders slow.  Does anyone have any suggestions on making the maps render much faster similar to google maps and microsoft virtual earth.

Comment: What products are you talking about? Is it ArcMap, ArcExplorer, or a web application such as one written in the .NET ADF or the Flex ADF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which product are you using? Desktop ArcGIS, ArcEngine, ArcGIS server, or what?

Not that it matters really. Rather than asking here, I think you'd be better off searching the [online ArcGIS support](http://support.esri.com/) or asking the question on an [ArcGIS forum](http://support.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=forums.gateway). For instance there's ESRI's [performance tips for desktop ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/news/podcasts/transcripts/performancetipsandtricks_arcgisdesktop.pdf). There aren't many ArcGIS experts hanging out here as far as I know.

Sorry Stack Overflow - love ya!

Comment: I think there's actually a few experts hanging around.  I find ESRI's forums really disappointing for the most part - I'd like to encourage *more* esri questions on Stack Overflow if possible ;)

Comment: Interesting view. I've just looked at the ArcGIS performance forum (just one of their many forums). Over 150 replies in the last 10 days. This place has about 10 replies for **all ArcGIS** questions in the same period. So I'm afraid I stand by my original advice. Particularly for a question like this which is not particularly programming related.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic map rendering speed is typically dominated by two factors: data access and label layout. Doing coordinate projection and typical 2D rendering happens about as fast as data can be read from an external source, e.g. shapefile or database. The trick is how much data are you loading to draw a map? And how long does it take to get it? Complicated DB queries may be causing inefficient queries. Querying data which is not indexed will cause slow downs. Even if you find data quickly, you need to be aware of how much you are loading. Does your data contain a very detailed single multi-part polygon for all of Canada's islands at high detail, but you are only rendering the US-Canada border in Wyoming?

Answer (score 2):

If you went to the ArcGIS forums you likely found an answer but I'll chime in here in case others come across the question.

The main reason for the speed of services like Google maps is that they pre-render and cache the data.  So they do the rendering for a variety of resolutions and store that so when a user request the data a raster of the data can be quickly delivered.

ArcMap does have an option to use map caching which should speed things up on repeat visits to views.  There is a map caching toolbar that can be turned on.  The ESRI help is generally pretty good on getting you started so just search for map cache.

Answer (score 2):

Both ArcMap and ArcGIS Server can use kind of cache that speeds up. In case of ArcMap it can be used for all kinds of data sources, drawback is that it can boost network activity when using non-local resources. In the ArcGIS Server, caching is the best way to provide user experience similar to GE.

All server client (Web ADF, JavaScript, ArcGIS Explorer) can then benefit from pre-computed map cache - the cache can be also delivered from static web server, too. Take a look at [resources.esri.com](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/), there is complete AGS help available, and within it you can find section [Planning a map cache](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotNet/index.htm#planning_a_map_cache.htm).

Answer (score 1):

map cache is only work for static map, but not dynamic layers. Dynamic layer is usually the bottle neck, it takes a long time to draw and rendered. For example, I have one dynamic layer that contains about 2000 locations, it takes about 9 seconds to rendered in ArcMap. And it takes about 15 secs to rendered in the GUI which is implemented in java ADF, JSF and JS. Any idea, how to improve the performance on the dynamic layers???

Thanks,
Don

Comment: I too am in java adf hell. Check out fiddler for ie. Watch what happens when you do a vertex move with the snaptool enabled.
The stupid thing is updating the editor window many many times for no good reason before actually moving the vertex. Fiddler will show you how poorly written the adf implementation truely is. Billions of 302 requests for images that have already been served. constant updating of div views that do not need it. For as much money as this software costs.... AHHHHHHRRRRRRGGGGGGHHHH!!!! its insane. I have an esri guy at my workplace right now. I hope he gets them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are few ways to make the maps load faster.  First, you can use the minimum amount of feature layers as possible. This way the amount of data to be loaded will be less, therefore less loading time. If you are the programmer doing the apps I suggest making the minimum amount of server calls because lading the tale images can be time consuming. Third,  if you are working with huge amounts of data I will suggest that you look at local storage in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I believe the *Basemap Layer* functionality added to ArcGIS 10.0 addressed these issues.

Rasters or Features that are static can be added to a basemap layer group and will not be recomputed when the map/layout view changes. They will be locked to a set resolution so features will not sharpen as you zoom in.

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/02/02/basemap-layers-new-at-arcgis-10/

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”